# How to detect current user inside a VSTS extension

Tags: azure-devops

I have an extension in VSTS which users from the server are able to interact with. My problem is just that i currently speak to a backend through MY credentials and i would like to create the authentication in such way that it will go through the individual user who is using the extension and not my account.

What is the most optimal way of handling this issue?